# Identify which textbox has fired a text changed event

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a number of text boxes that are dynamically created via code.

I would like to be able to assign a generic event handler to all the textboxes for the text changed even and then within the handler determine which text box has fired the event.

Code I have is:

```
txtStringProperty.TextChanged += TextBoxValueChanged;

private void TextBoxValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string propertyName = // I would like the name attribute of the textbox here
}
```

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: You probably shouldn't create controls "via code" but use [data templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sender` parameter contains which control has fired the event. You can cast it to a TextBox and get the name property from it:

```
string propertyName = ((TextBox)sender).Name;
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought this may be the case but wanted to check this was the recognised way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Cast `object sender`(your textbox which fired event) to `TextBox`.

If only one property is what you want then write

```
string propertyName = ((TextBox)sender).Name;
```

But when more than one property is required, then it is better to create a Textbox variable and use it like.

```
TextBox txtbox =  (TextBox)sender;
```

Then you can use any property of it like

```
string propertyName = txtbox.Name; 

MessageBox.Show(proptertyName);
MessageBox.Show(txtbox.Content.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to look at the base class hierarchy at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) 
and just cast the control to it and extract the properties defined on it:

```
var name = ((ContentControl) sender).Name;
```

this is also a good practice for a more generic implementation because casting it to 'TextBox' means you can apply the handling logic to that type of control only.