# pass control ID to custom method on text changed event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I would like to write a single method to handle the text changed event of several server controls on a webform.  When the text changed event fires I need to pass the control ID to my method.  In other words, when my method is called, I have to figure out which control caused the text changed event to fire.  Is this possible?  Normally I would use the command argument property but I don't think this is available for textbox and listbox controls.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the sender parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583824/identify-which-textbox-has-fired-a-text-changed-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Sender` (first) parameter in the TextChanged function:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

        if (tb != null)
        {
            string id = tb.ID;
        }
 }
```

Comment: hmm, guess i was making this more complicated than it needed to be

Answer (score 1):

your event handler has two parameters: `object sender, eventargs e`

The sender parameter is what you're looking for. Its actually a reference to the object which called the event handler, you just have to cast it to the correct type.

```
 TextBox fooBar = sender as TextBox;
```

then you can get the name if you desire:

```
 if(fooBar.Name == "someName") { ... }
```