# c# count characters of multiple text boxes

Tags: c#, textbox, string-length

I have two (and going to be more but for this example I will keep it to two) text boxes that I want to total the character count into one label.

The two text boxes I have are called probDescTextbox and stepsToRepoTextbox.

I am using winforms and a TextChanged event. I am not sure if there is a way to get this to work without having multiple TextChanged events but if i nest it i get an error and if i make a second one, i cannot seem to get the numbers to add.

CODE:

```
    private void probDescTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int probDescLimit = probDescTextBox.Text.Length;
        int stepsToRepoLimit = stepsToRepoTextBox.Text.Length;
        int charLimit = probDescLimit + stepsToRepoLimit;

        if (charLimit >= 50)
        {
            probDescCharLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            probDescCharLabel.Text = charLimit.ToString() + " Over Limit!!";
        }
        else
        {
            probDescCharLabel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            probDescCharLabel.Text = charLimit.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I am sure this is simple enough but I cannot find an example using multiple text boxes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried pointing the events of both textboxes to the same method?

Comment: You can point all of the `TextChanged` events at the same event handler, if that's all that each of them need to do - no need for the same code in each one.  Depending on how many text boxes you're talking about, you could create a list holding them all, and use a bit of Linq or a loop to get the total length of all of them, rather than querying the `.Length` property individually

Comment: Is this code the working version or the non-working version?  For the non-working version, what's the error?

Comment: what kind of error do you have?

Comment: What do you mean by a "character"? A UTF-16 codeunit? A unicode codepoint? A single symbol?

Comment: @David This code works but only when i type in probDescText box do the characters count up. CodesInChaos by character i mean just normal text.

Comment: @jAC: That implies that the event handler is only invoked by that one text box.  Does the other text box invoke a `TextChanged` handler?

Comment: @David ahh, no it does. If I invoke both textboxes, how would I get the label to display the changes as I would have to combine the count (length)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wire the text change event to the same handler.

**Edit:**

1.) Change the name of your event handler to something more generic so that you know it's not specific to the `probDescTextBox`:

```
 private void note_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Same code as you have above, or see note...
    }
```

**Note**: If you need to know which textbox fired the event see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583848/301703).  You can inspect the sender.  This will allow you to only set the forecolor of the textbox which fired the event.

2.) Wire up the event handler in your form's constructor as shown below, or if you're using the designer, change the values in each text box's properties window:

```
public MyForm()
{
     //wire each textbox's TextChanged event to the same handler
     probDescTextBox.TextChanged += note_TextChanged;
     stepsToRepoTextbox.TextChanged += note_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Noel Could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: oh man, that was so much easier than what i was trying. Thanks a million!